# Wordpress Setting a Cookie to change Stylesheet

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have been trying to set a cookie which will change the stylesheet of the theme based on a button click. I can't figure out why it isn't working, please could someone explain where I am going wrong?

These are my buttons (header.php):

```
<a href="?style=as1" >AS1</a>
<a href="?style=as2" >AS2</a> 
<a href="?style=as3" >AS3</a>
```

This is my stylesheet (header.php):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" id="accessible-stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/<?php echo $stylesheet; ?>" />
```

This is my function (functions.php):

```
// Accessible Stylesheet Cookie

$stylesheet = "as1";

if ( isset($_GET['style']) ) {
  if ($_GET['style'] == "as2") {

    $stylesheet = "as2";

  } else if ($_GET['style'] == "as3") {

    $stylesheet = "as3";

  }

  setcookie("style","$stylesheet","3600*7");  
}

$as1stylesheet = 'css/colors-as1.css';
$as2stylesheet = 'css/colors-as2.css';
$as3stylesheet = 'css/colors-as3.css';


$stylesheet = $as1stylesheet;


if ( isset($_COOKIE['stylesheet'] ) ) {
   if ( $_COOKIE['stylesheet'] == "as2" ) {

        $stylesheet = $as2stylesheet;

    } else if ( $_COOKIE['stylesheet'] == "as3" ) {

        $stylesheet = $as3stylesheet;

    }
}
```

I am getting no errors, I can't figure out where I am going wrong. The stylesheet isn't being set at all.

Comment: Where in your order of operations are you setting the cookie?

Comment: @HowardE What do you mean? Have I missed a vital bit? This is my first time using cookies, so apologies if I have.

Comment: You have to set cookies before headers are sent. (if you're using PHP setcookie)

Comment: If i have it all currently in the header.php above the wp_head(); is that right?

Comment: Yes.  Just checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your PHP code, and are using the variables incorrectly.  This seems more concise.

You can't set and call the superglobal $_COOKIE on the same page.  Here's an excerpt from the manual... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.

```php
$stylesheet = "as1";
// Check for cookie and set one if it's not set
if (!isset($_COOKIE['style'])) setcookie('style', $stylesheet, time() + (3600*7));

// If there is a cookie, the stylesheet is from the cookie
if ( isset($_COOKIE['style'] ) ) {
    $stylesheet = $_COOKIE['style'];
}

// If there's a get parameter set the cookie to it (for next page load), and set the stylesheet for this page load
if ( isset($_GET['style']) ) {
  $stylesheet = $_GET['style'];
  setcookie('style', $stylesheet, time() + (3600*7));
}
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" id="accessible-stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/colors-<?php echo $stylesheet; ?>.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie name is style and you are trying to retrieve the cookie stylesheet

`setcookie("style","$stylesheet","3600*7");` and you don't need to put the value in quotes if you are only going to put a variable in it:
`setcookie("stylesheet",$stylesheet,"3600*7");`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, this doesn't fix the issue? There is still nothing happening? 
I have tried putting all the code in header.php which now shows the first initial stylesheet but doesn't change upon button click?